# How to make Jenkins to build an AngularJS app from one GIT Repository and execute tests from a separate Repository

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to implement Jenkins for our test project. My expected workflow is as follows:

1. Jenkins will build the app (AngularJS) when the developers push the code to the app in GIT Repo (NPM start)
2. Jenkins will start the app ( /> ng serve) -- This will start the server at localhost:4200
3. Jenkins will switch to the Test Script repository
4. Jenkins will start the test execution
5. Jenkins will close the server once the tests are executed

My problems are:

a. when Jenkins builds at the end of step 2. It is creating a server instance which will continue to run. In this situation, the command window is dedicated to the server and it is not accepting any commands. So How can I make jenkins to move to the test directory and start testing the app?

b. At the end of the process, How to stop the server through Jenkins without manually typing "Ctl+C"?

Comment: Your setup is crazy. Typically, you want your tests to be in your apps same repo, and launch them with a command rather than having to build and serve the app

Answer (score 0):

Separate your builds.
One pipeline is built from the main repo.
The second pipeline is fetching from test repo and run tests.
First pipeline

```
node("main") {
   stage("build") {
      git url: "https://github.com/your project repo",  credentialsId: "[credentials if need or avoid this param]", branch: "branch name"
       rest of steps
   }

   stage("Test") {
      build job:"TestJob", wait: true
   }
}
```

And TestJob job code:

```
node("main") {
   stage("build") {
      git url: "https://github.com/your test repo",  credentialsId: "[credentials if need or avoid this param]", branch: "branch name"
       rest steps to test app
    } 
 }
```

You can check [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#-build-%20build%20a%20job) of running build step